# Matlab: pixel values of multiple .jpg images

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, jpeg

I have a couple hundred images like this one:

[image]

They are in a single folder and am trying to figure out a way in Matlab to automatically analyze each image's pixel values at point `(700,755)`.  I know how to do this one-at-a-time, as such:

```
rgb=impixel(p,700,755)
```

This returns the red-green-blue values at that particular point for the image.  I'm very new to Matlab...what piece of code would analyze each image in the folder and save the `RGB` value on separate lines in a table/array?

Also, I have selected an area using the pixel region tool:  '[696.463836477986 750.095011390851 19.9889937106933 13.3672527600921]'  How do I analyze all the pixel values in that area and get the statistics (min, max, mean, etc.)...plus do that for all 200 images I have in the folder?

I appreciate the help!
AP

Answer (score 2):

`impixel` can work for all the image as well:

```
impixel(I)
```

or for a specific (pixel) column and row:

```
impixel(I,c,r)
```

But you need first to read the image into a matrix. The `imread` function, returns all the `RGB` data of an image in an array:

```
A = imread(filename, fmt)
```

it reads a `grayscale` or `color` image from the file specified by the string `filename`. A is an array containing the image data. If the file contains a 'grayscale' image, A is an 'M-by-N' array. If the file contains a 'truecolor' image, A is an 'M-by-N-by-3' array. (3: R-G-B)

To read a bunch of files in a folder do this:

```
files = dir('*.jpg');
for i=1:length(files)
    eval(['imread ' files(i).name]);
end
```

You can use `imcrop` function to crop the images you have:

using mouse:

```
I2 = imcrop(I)
```

or using dimensions:

```
I2 = imcrop(I,[75 68 130 112]);
```

Comment: how would I use impixel for all the images in a single folder?

Comment: Okay...so imread reads all it to a matrix and the code above worked...but now how do I extract the individual pixel values from each of those matrices that imread just did?